# Does openssl's low level API automatically add padding?

Tags: openssl, padding, 3des, ecb

I know that block cipher mode such as ecb and cbc requires padding. I also know that openssl command line tool can switch between add padding/no padding. But does openssl's low level API automatically add padding? Specifically `DES_ecb3_encrypt()` / `DES_ecb3_encrypt()`.

PS: I checked the EVP interface source code, and it seems the padding operation is done at EVP level. When padding is required, after encryping data using `DES_ecb3_encrypt()`, EVP will also encrypt padding part.